Getting following error while upgrading java 8 to java 11, and spring version from 4.3 to 5.3.1
Below is the log details.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.thucydides.maven.plugins:maven-thucydides-plugin:0.9.268:aggregate (thucydides-reports) on project tspservice-automation-tests: Execution thucydides-reports of goal net.thucydides.maven.plugins:maven-thucydides-plugin:0.9.268:aggregate failed: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[ERROR] at net.thucydides.core.reports.json.jackson.JacksonJSONConverter.(JacksonJSONConverter.java:32)
[ERROR] while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.jackson.JacksonJSONConverter
[ERROR] at net.thucydides.core.guice.ThucydidesModule.configure(ThucydidesModule.java:57)
[ERROR] while locating net.thucydides.core.reports.json.JSONConverter

I tried with following dependency in pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


Since the error seems to happen in maven build, did you try adding the jaxb dependencies as dependencies of the maven-plugin ? The plugin is 10 years old by the way, maybe it's not jdk11 compatible...

jakarta.xml is not javax.xml. At Spring 5, you should still be using javax, so I think you need to change your pom dependency.

@dbreaux: JAXB version 2.x is still javax. JAXB version 3.x is the first to use jakarta package. So that's not the issue here. Laurent is right, the Maven plugin mentioned in error message is not Java 11 compatible and needs to be adjusted/upgraded/replaced.
